# Evaluate $\lim_{y\to\\+0} \int_{0}^{1} \exp\left(-\frac{\arctan x}{y}\right)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I am trying to evaluate the following 
$$\lim_{y\to\\+0} \int_{0}^{1} \exp\left(-\frac{\arctan x}{y}\right)\,\mathrm  dx$$
Seems useful to bring limit under integral, but can't see the solution. Please help.

Comment: Is the numerator meant to be $\arctan x$?

Comment: If you bring the limit under the integral, what is, for a fixed $x$, $$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \exp \left(-\frac{\arctan x}{y}\right)\,?$$

Comment: @DanielFischer so the answer might be zero?

Comment: It is. Go prove it in your favourite way. (Monotone convergence, dominated convergence, other means)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change variables $x = \tan z$ then the integral is
$$\int_0^{\pi \over 4} e^{-{z \over y}}\sec^2 z \, dz$$
Since $0 \leq \sec^2 z \leq 2$ on the range of integration, the integral is between $0$ and
$$ 2\int_0^{\pi \over 4} e^{-{z \over y}}\, dz$$
It's now straightforward to perform the integral and verify the limit is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Split the integral into two pieces, one on $[0,\epsilon/2]$ and one on $[\epsilon/2,1]$.

The first one is less than $\epsilon/2$. For $y$ close enough to zero, the latter can be made less than $\epsilon/2$ because arctan is bounded between its (positive) value at $\epsilon/2$ and by one.